# how to store SQL query result in data frame in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to R and i am using shiny package to build a shiny app that can take different type of queries and those queries takes dynamic user id provided by users on ui level and also i want to show the demo of result of query on ui.
So, my problem is that i am not able to store the query results into an data frame also on clicking on Download button csv is not storing in my system. my code is below. thanks.

```
###server

library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
datasetInput <- reactive({
switch(input$queryset,
       "CDR" = cdr,
       "ASSET" = ast,
       "USAGE" = usg)
})
output$tbl <- renderTable({
conn <- dbConnect(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "xxxx",
host =   "xxxxxx",
username = "xxxxx",
password = "xxxxx"),
q<-dbSendQuery(conn,paste0("select * from table where user_id='",input$user_id,"' and start_time >= '2016-07-16' and start_time < '2016-07-28' order by start_time limit 10 ;",sep = ""
))
dat<- dbFetch(q,n=-1)
on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
})
output$view <- renderTable({
head({dat}, n = input$nrows)
})
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() { paste(input$user_id, '.csv', sep='') },
content = function(file) {
write.csv({dat}, file)
})
}
)

###ui
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("My App"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("queryset", "Choose the type of query:", 
              choices = c("CDR", "ASSET", "USAGE")),
numericInput("nrows", "Enter the no. of observations:", 10),
numericInput("user_id", "Enter user_id:", 0),
downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download',class = NULL)
),
mainPanel(
tableOutput("view")
)
)
))
```

Comment: So what happens when you run your code? What's the error?

Comment: It just simply shows the ui components. it is not storing query result into data frame also not showing the query result on ui.
Also, on clicking on Download button prompt shows up to save the file but it is not saving the file as well.

Comment: @Hack-R can u help?